# Why web page loaded in iFrame has no css applied in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a web page that has a lot of CSS in it. I use an iframe to load it. It is working perfectly on almost each browser, but on IE version 7 no CSS is applied at all. When I open the page in a separate tab under IE7 it works, but it iframe even a line of CSS is not applied?

Can anyone give me some tips from where to start the searching?

Any helpwill be appreciated.

EDIT: The main web page has the following doc-type:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
```

I am not sure if it is true, but I have read that the strict doc-type could cause problems with iframe on older browsers. Could this broke the css of the frame?

Comment: To answer your last question...yes it could.  iframes are not covered in the strict doctype.  Try using transitional, or just use html5 short style.  Until then you're trying to work through something that is broken for no reason and just hoping the browsers will clean it up for you.

Comment: Please share a link to your website. We can help solve it if we can recreate the error here.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I am not allowed to share the link due to security issues and I know that this makes the situation a kind of ridiculous because I am asking you to help to fix something that you are not able to see. I even have not access to all the code myself, and what I am hoping is that someone has met the same issue and solve it.

Comment: What mime-type is the css request served with?

Comment: @gotqn, if you use absolute or relative path for stylesheets? have you try `base` tag? this might make sense http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937266

Comment: What protocol (e.g. "http" or "https") is the iframe webpage loaded through, and what is the protocol of the css reference inside the iframe? If the webpage is https, then the css needs to be loaded from the same server through https as well. Though it seems this would cause problems in more than just IE7.

Comment: can you add sample code  example on jsfiddle.net with dummy content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

I solved using this.

Comment: This should be set in the iframe page on in the  page that crate the iframe?

Comment: I have add this on both pages - the one that holds the iframe and the one that is loaded in iframe but nothing has changed.

Comment: Thanks gotqn for accepting me in bounty...did you develop freetibet.org? I am from India and support...

Comment: No, I am just a supporter :- ]

Answer (score 3):

CSS information does not cascade into iframe. You need to add CSS references onto the page that is put into the iframe. Some of the ways to get CSS into a page include:

### With a style tag

```
<style type="text/css">
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
</style>
```

With iframes, you would have to copy this over and over again. (Not recommended)

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp

### With a reference to a style sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

With iframes you would have to copy just link part into your `<head>` area of the page

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

This is not a IE7 thing. This is for all browsers that support CSS

Comment: Do you mean I need to copy the CSS classes from the web page loaded in the frame to the main web page? And why this is not working only in IE7?

Comment: There are (at least) two approaches to getting css information into a page.

Comment: I think you have misunderstand me. The page that I load in frame has own styles, and if it is opened as a separate page, the styles are shown. If it is load in frame, the styles are not shown. And this is case only in IE7.

Comment: In that case, you should try the "X-UA-Compatible" thing

Answer (score 2):

1)hopefully iframe tags are closed properly

```
<IFRAME SRC='gnagna.htm' STYLE='width:100%;'></IFRAME>
```

set width with  css
or

```
<iframe src="somepage.htm"  frameborder=0 scrolling="auto" width="800" height="600"> This browser can not use IFRAME. </iframe>
```

2) may be try using these

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
```

3)

You can force Ie7 compatibility by adding this in head section

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
</head>
```

or

quicker way is to add the following line to .htaccess

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=EmulateIE7
```

4)

or you can apply css styling hack for ie7/ie6

```
.somediv
{
height:30px;
*height:30px; //hack for ie7 
_height:30px; //hack for ie6
}
```

hope it helps